# Special character issue in page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Problem: Hi, this ‡ character is getting rendered correctly on my webapp.
I have tried using html entity as well but still its showing as Ã¢â‚¬Â¡ Or â€¡.

Comment: Make sure the character encoding of the file matches the character encoding of the page.

Comment: Try to add `<meta charset="utf-8" />` to your html

Comment: Thanks Quang, I'd tried adding that as well previously in the html file, but the results were same.

Answer (score 0):

The caracter ‡ or maybe similar to not equal to (≠) , was a scpecial character.

And need another syntax, to be shown like that.

I can recommend you to use this line of code

```html
<span style='font-size:100px;'>&#8800;</span>
```

For more details, we can read this [link of reference](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_math.asp) .

Hope it was helpful.

Thank you